# Antenna with AC current

Tags: antenna

1. Do antennas need an oscillator to get or make frequencies or is an AC input enough to generate a frequency by its antenna length?
2. Does converting DC to AC by using a crystal oscillator, make the output plus and minus at ground and/or is it enough to use a DC voltage with oscillator to make the antenna work?

Comment: how do you get an AC input without an oscillator?

Comment: Please clarify the question. A receiving antenna does not need an AC input from an oscillator to work at all. A transmitting antenna needs a transmit signal, which is usually already a modulated AC carrier, so no additional oscillator would be required. Why do you think you need an additional oscillator?

Comment: A suggestion to take in context of the answer(s) already given: It may help you to think of an antenna, *conceptually*, as nothing more than a weirdly shaped transformer where one side is connected to an electronic circuit like a normal transformer, but the other side is "connected" to the electromagnetic field in the space around the antenna rather than to a wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The antenna must be excited with its own tolerating frequency. Most often crystals are used with transistors for proper oscillating. While signal is coming from input, it will be oscillated through crystal and when it arrives the transistor then the amplifier will respond during oscillating with higher AC voltage feeding the antenna.

Answer (score 2):

> Do antennas need an oscillator to get or make frequencies or is an AC
> input enough to generate a frequency by its antenna length?

Yes, you must 'excite' the antenna at the frequency that it radiates, it won't radiate without excitation.

> Does converting DC to AC by using a crystal oscillator, make the
> output plus and minus at ground and/or is it enough to use a DC
> voltage with oscillator to make the antenna work?

Depends on the circuit, the antenna radiates relative to what the input voltage of it's terminals are. Think with respect to what the antennas inputs are vs relative to ground. You must use a circuit that creates an AC excitation voltage for the antenna, many circuits do this with a DC input.

Comment: circuits which creates AC outputs with DC inputs are called oscillators

Comment: @user253751 that's true, for AC in the strict sense; if all you want is "some power spectral density in the RF range", there's some spontaneous / chaotic systems – noise generators – which don't oscillate but will still excite an antenna :)

Comment: @user253751 UWB uses a broadband pulse to excite it's antenna.

Answer (score 2):

Until the advent of the vacuum-tube oscillator, rotating machines known as alternators were used as transmitters by radiotelegraphy stations.

An [Alexanderson alternator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexanderson_alternator) is a rotating machine invented by Ernst Alexanderson in 1904 for the generation of high-frequency alternating current for use as a radio transmitter. It was one of the first devices capable of generating the continuous radio waves needed for transmission of amplitude modulated signals by radio. It was used from about 1910 in a few "superpower" longwave radiotelegraphy stations to transmit transoceanic message traffic by Morse code to similar stations all over the world.

A 200 kW Alexanderson alternator preserved at the [Grimeton radiotelegraphy station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimeton_Radio_Station), Sweden is the only remaining example of an Alexanderson transmitter.

Each year, on a day called Alexanderson Day, either on the last Sunday in June, or on the first Sunday in July, whichever comes closer to 2 July, the Grimeton station holds an open house during which the transmitter is started up and transmits test messages on 17.2 kHz using its call sign SAQ, which can be received all over Europe.